# Is there any way or tool in SQL Server to find a column in the entire database based on the web page field name?

Tags: sql-server

We have a web base tool where its database is SQL Server and we don't have an idea what could be the name of the column in database wrt field name on the web page.

We don't have access to the code. Is there any possible way to find the names in database column names?

Comment: Strictly speaking, no - because the field displayed on the web-page could be a composite from various other fields (e.g. a "Person's name" field on a web-page could be comprised of separate `FirstName` and `LastName` fields). That said, why not dump the table's data and compare that to the data displayed on-screen?

Answer (score 1):

You can use  ;

```
SELECT * FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

view and you can look at the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/183/informationschemacolumns/) article about this view.

Answer (score 1):

Following code can help in finding the column name along with the table name in the database:

```
use <replace with DB_Name>
GO 
select * from information_schema.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME like '%<replace with column_name>%'


/*Also remove the angular brackets<> as well while replacing the column_name and DB_Name */
```

Answer (score 0):

The [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) view allows you to get information about all columns for all tables and views within a database :

```
SELECT * FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

To query for just one table you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable'
```